# How to convert hexadecimal values to Base64 in Rust

Tags: hex, base64, rust

I'm having some issues understanding the concept of traits in Rust. I'm trying to encode a simple hex value to Base64 but with no luck, here is my code (with an example of string to Base64 also)

```
extern crate serialize;

use serialize::base64::{ToBase64, STANDARD};
use serialize::hex::{FromHex, ToHex};

fn main () {
  let stringOfText = "This is a String";
  let mut config = STANDARD;

  println!("String to base64 = {}", stringOfText.as_bytes().to_base64(config));

  // Can't figure out this
```

The solution provided by Vladimir works for 0x notated hex values. Now I'm looking to convert a hex value that is represented in a string:

```
extern crate serialize;

use serialize::base64::{ToBase64, STANDARD};
use serialize::hex::{FromHex, ToHex};
fn main () {
  let stringOfText = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
  let mut config = STANDARD;

  println!("String to base64 = {}", stringOfText.from_hex().from_utf8_owned().as_bytes().to_base64(config));

  // result should be: SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t

}
```

`from_hex()` gives me a `Vec<u8>` and `.to_base64()` is expecting a buffer of `u8,` first I thought to convert the `Vec<u8>` to string and then use the `as_bytes()` to get the buffer, so far still no luck.

Comment: The only implementor of `ToBase64` trait is `&[u8]` (http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/base64/trait.ToBase64.html) , so you will need to convert that number to it before you can use `to_base64()`.

Comment: Thank you @snf , just updated to this
  
  `let hex = 0x49276d2;`

  `let integer = hex as u8;`

  `println!("Hex to base64 = {}", integer.to_base64(config));`
 
 
but still no luck

Comment: I don't get what you want to do, do you want to base64_encode "0x49276d2" or "\x04\x92\x76\xd2" or something else?

Comment: @david-dias Could you please change the accepted answer to the one that works in 2017?

Comment: Done, thanks for the ping! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is now 2017, and rustc-serialize is now deprecated as well (see [here](https://github.com/rust-lang-deprecated/rustc-serialize)).  The new big serialization library is called [serde](https://serde.rs) but I think that's a little heavy for this problem.

Here's a quick solution that manually converts from the `String` of hex to a `Vec<u8>` and then uses [this](https://crates.io/crates/base64) to convert to a base64-encoded `String`.

I am not convinced that this for loop is anywhere near the best solution for converting a `String` of hex into a `Vec<u8>`, but I'm fairly new to Rust and this is all I've got.  Comments/improvements are appreciated.

(Hey, wait a minute, I recognize these encoded strings, are you doing [cryptopals](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/1)?)

```rust
extern crate base64;
use std::u8;
use base64::{Engine as _, engine::general_purpose};

pub fn hex_to_base64(hex: String) -> String {

    // Make vector of bytes from octets
    let mut bytes = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..(hex.len()/2) {
        let res = u8::from_str_radix(&hex[2*i .. 2*i+2], 16);
        match res {
            Ok(v) => bytes.push(v),
            Err(e) => println!("Problem with hex: {}", e),
        };
    };

    general_purpose::STANDARD.encode(&bytes) // now convert from Vec<u8> to b64-encoded String
}
```

Comment: I don't know about OP, but I am. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: Four years later... Sure am!

Comment: Hey, I'm doing cryptopals too. Was it good? Would you recommend me doing it? And are there better resources to dive deep into cryptography and bytes manipulation?

Comment: Now you'd need to use `base64::engine::general_purpose` to get the `encode` method. See https://docs.rs/base64/0.21.2/base64/engine/trait.Engine.html#method.encode

Answer (score 10):

Rust is currently evolving, and the accepted answer does not work properly any more. Specifically, the `extern crate` statement does not allow quoted parameters, and the name of the rustc-serialize crate is now `rustc_serialize`.

The following code correctly base64 encodes the string, yielding the same result as the accepted answer (rustc 1.3.0):

```rust
extern crate rustc_serialize as serialize;

use serialize::base64::{self, ToBase64};
use serialize::hex::FromHex;

fn main() {
    let input = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
    let result = input.from_hex().unwrap().to_base64(base64::STANDARD);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Result:

> SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t

Answer (score 4):

For your updated question, try this:

```
extern crate "rustc-serialize" as serialize;

use serialize::base64::{self, ToBase64};
use serialize::hex::FromHex;

fn main() {
    let input = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
    let result = input.from_hex().unwrap().as_slice().to_base64(base64::STANDARD);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

(Note that serialize is now in an external crate, see [rustc-serialize](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-serialize). Thanks to [gsingh2011](https://stackoverflow.com/users/803801/gsingh2011).)

`from_hex` returns a `Result<Vec<u8>, FromHexError>`, which is unwrapped to a `Vec<u8>`, then used as a `&[u8]` with `as_slice()`.

`Result` is a type that is either `Ok` or `Err` and is usually returned from methods that can fail to compute a result. In the above case `unwrap` is used to get to the `Ok` value. If the result wasn't `Ok`, it fails (try it by removing one of the letters from the string).

Depending on what your program does, the error case should be handled explicitly using a match:

```
match input.from_hex() {
    Ok(result) => println!("Yay: {}", result.as_slice().to_base64(base64::STANDARD)),
    Err(error) => println!("Nay: {}", error)
}
```

Or if you just want to continue with a default value, you can use `unwrap_or`:

```
println!("{}", input.from_hex().unwrap_or(vec!()).as_slice().to_base64(base64::STANDARD));
```

See [documentation for Result](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) for other methods.

Comment: Thank you so much Robinst! So if I understand correctly, A Rust best practice is to return a result and error inside a 'package' that then has to be unwrapped to get the actual result (or error in case of error?)

Comment: Yes, I added more explanation for that in the answer. Other languages sometimes use exceptions for this, or multiple return values. Rust has a type with nice methods, that allows the caller to handle it one way or another.

Comment: Note that the base64 conversion functions have moved to an external crate: https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-serialize

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what do you mean - convert hex value to base64 (fwiw there is no such thing as hex value - it's just another form of the same literal number). Assuming that you want to convert bytes which make up `int` value, you can do something like this:

```
extern crate serialize;

use std::mem;
use serialize::base64::{mod, ToBase64};

fn decompose_int(n: int, buf: &mut [u8]) {
    assert!(mem::size_of::<int>() == buf.len());
    for i in range(0, buf.len()) {
        buf[i] = ((n >> i*8) & 0xFF) as u8;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bytes = [0u8, ..8];
    let x = 0x1122334455667788;
    decompose_int(x, &mut bytes);
    println!("{}", bytes.to_base64(base64::STANDARD));
}
```

(try it [here](http://is.gd/LiN4HZ))

Here `decompose_int` function serializes an `int` value into a slice of bytes in little endian format. Then this slice is converted to base64 as usual.

If you need big endian representation, you will need to change `buf[i]` to `buf[buf.len()-1-i]`.

Comment: Thank you :) . Exactly, I just want to understand how to make that first step in Rust. Thank you for your solution it definitely works for 0x values (as I've asked.) Now I'm trying to use a String to represent a hex value, which requires me to convert it to a vector of bytes (see updates on top).

Comment: do you think it's a good idea to modify parameters - `buf[i] = `? Instead there must be another variable `let buf1 = buf; buf1[i] = ...`

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, why? I see no reason for the temporary variable.

Comment: in general, modifying parameters is bad, haven't your heard of this?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, this *may* be so when you're modifying parameters themselves (e.g. in this case it would be if you replaced one slice with the other, but it is impossible since `buf` variable is not mutable), and I'd argue that even this is debatable in Rust. Moreover, here the slice itself is mutable, and its sole reason of existence is to allow mutating its elements. Adding a local variable brings nothing more than confusion. Sorry, but applying such rules without thinking is a very wrong approach.

Comment: "this may be so when you're modifying parameters themselves" -> isn't this what I'm talking about?

Comment: No. Here the parameter itself is not modified, and it can't be, because it is not `mut buf: &mut [u8]`. `buf` is a mutable slice and it is used to mutate elements which are contained somewhere else.